# Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity is changed after set in firstTime

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-principal

I have a simple wpf sample(a window with a button) .I set Thread.CurrentPrincipal  in constructor like:

```
//my Window constructor
public Window1(){
InitializeComponent();
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());   
}
```

and I watch that Thread.CurrentPrincipal is correct.

I put a breakepoint in buttonclick event .after I click button I check Thread.CurrentPrincipal but it's change and my it's identity Name is empty

Comment: Can you post example code? Is it still the same thread? Are the other values of the current thread still the same? For example the managed thread id?

Comment: @nvoigt It has just this code.I add watch on Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name in constructor and i see my windows username.aftre i click on button my watch value be empty...

Comment: Constructor of what?

Comment: @HenkHolterman my Window constructor

Comment: It helps to be clear about that. Also about the InitializeComponent() that's usually there (before/after/removed?)

Comment: For what it's worth, I can confirm this. It does stick when set in the button-event but somehow it's reset after Window_Loaded, the last startup event that I know of.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I set  CurrentPrincipal after InitializeComponent()

Comment: I am seeing the same thing, it's frustrating.